# Filling a barrel, using small containers

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways, using containers, one with 2 liters and other with 7 liters, can you fill a barrel of 1234 liters?
What's the fastest and what's the slowest way to fill the barrel?

Should I use formula for permutation *n!/(n−r)!* or the other formula *n!/r!-(n−r)!* . In similar tasks I don't know which formula should be used.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you're filling some 2 litre barrels and then some 7 little barrels, and pouring them together to make 1234 litres. Does the order matter? If not, then you're essentially looking for the number of integer solutions to
$$
2a + 7b = 1234
$$

Comment: Order does not metter. Using that equation how can I find what's the fastest and what's the slowest way to fill the barrel?

Comment: Since your problem definition is not mentioning anything about time (for ex, how long it takes to fill a 2 / 7 litre barrel, or how long it takes to pour a barrel into the big barrel), it's a bit tricky to model the problem that way.

Comment: Some thoughts: Since $2a+7b = 1234$, we can take mod 7 on both sides, resulting in
$$
2a \equiv 2 \Rightarrow a \equiv 1 ~\text{mod}\ 7
$$
In addition, $a \geq 0$ and $a \leq \frac{1234}{2} = 617$. Then, how many numbers that are $\equiv 1~\text{mod}~7$ between $0$ and $617$ ?

Comment: I thought solving this as Diophantine equation.

Comment: Presumably, the slowest way is to just use 2-liter containers, and the fastest is to use as many 7-liter containers as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of using the $2$ and $7$ liter barrels does not matter then you do not need combinations or permutations. You simply need to find the number of solutions to

$2a + 7b = 1234$

where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers (you can use $0$ barrels of either size, but you cannot use $-1$ barrels).

So the minimum value of $a$ is $0$. And the maximum value is $\frac{1234}{2}=617$. So we have

$0 \le a \le 617$

In addition, to make $7b=1234 - 2a$ a multiple of $7$, we must have $a \mod 7 = 1$.

So $a$ can be $1, 8, 15, 22, \dots, 610, 617$. The corresponding values of $b$ are $176, 174, 172, 170, \dots, 2, 0$.

From this you should be able to work out how many possible values there are for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How many possible values for a and b, do i use the formula for binomial coefficient? Thank you.

Comment: You are over-complicating this. Look at the possible values for $b$. How many integers between $0$ and $176$ inclusive are multiples of $2$ ?